# Will I be among the 70,000 people if Ruqya was done without my permission?

Tags: hadith, jannah, ruqya

Salam brothers and sisters.

I read in hadees that if Muslim did ruqya he will not be in 70000 people entering paradise without any question.

I think when I wasn’t adult my parents and brothers used to recite Quran verses for my health. Now I feel like I will not be in those people entering paradise without any question.

But you see I didn’t knew about ruqya stuff and it’s effects since I was kid.

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/4203

Comment: I don't really understand this question

Answer (score 1):

The hadith you are referring to is a *sahīh* (authentic) hadith in [Sahih al-Bukhari 81/61](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/81/61), [Sahih Muslim 1/433](https://sunnah.com/muslim:218b), and [Jami' at-Tirmidhi 4/11/2446](https://sunnah.com/urn/726290), among other books of hadith:

> حَدَّثَنَا يَحْيَى بْنُ خَلَفٍ الْبَاهِلِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا الْمُعْتَمِرُ، عَنْ هِشَامِ بْنِ حَسَّانَ، عَنْ مُحَمَّدٍ، - يَعْنِي ابْنَ سِيرِينَ - قَالَ حَدَّثَنِي عِمْرَانُ، قَالَ قَالَ نَبِيُّ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم: يَدْخُلُ الْجَنَّةَ مِنْ أُمَّتِي سَبْعُونَ أَلْفًا بِغَيْرِ حِسَابٍ.‏ قَالُوا وَمَنْ هُمْ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ قَالَ: هُمُ الَّذِينَ لاَ يَكْتَوُونَ وَلاَ يَسْتَرْقُونَ وَعَلَى رَبِّهِمْ يَتَوَكَّلُونَ.‏ فَقَامَ عُكَّاشَةُ فَقَالَ ادْعُ اللَّهَ أَنْ يَجْعَلَنِي مِنْهُمْ.‏ قَالَ: نْتَ مِنْهُمْ‏.‏ قَالَ فَقَامَ رَجُلٌ فَقَالَ يَا نَبِيَّ اللَّهِ ادْعُ اللَّهَ أَنْ يَجْعَلَنِي مِنْهُمْ.‏ قَالَ: سَبَقَكَ بِهَا عُكَّاشَةُ.‏
>
> It is reported on the authority of 'Imran that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: Seventy thousand people of my Ummah would be admitted into Paradise without rendering any account. They (the companions) said: Who would be of those (fortunate persons)? He (the Holy Prophet) said: Those who do not cauterise and practise charm, but repose trust in their Lord, 'Ukkasha then stood up and said: Supplicate (before) Allah that He should make me one among them. He (the Holy Prophet) said: Thou art one among them He (the narrator) said: A man stood up and said: Apostle of Allah, supplicate (before) Allah that He should make me one among them. He (the Prophet said: 'Ukkasha has preceded you (in this matter).
>
> <sub>— [Sahih Muslim, Book 1, Hadith 432](https://sunnah.com/muslim:218a)</sub>

The hadith does not say, as per your understanding of it, that a Muslim who does have *ruqyāh* practiced on them, which is *yurqawn* (Arabic: يرقون), will not be among the 70,000 people entering paradise without rendering account; rather, it says those who do not request from others to perform *ruqyāh* on them, which is *yastarqūn* (Arabic: يسترقون).

If your parents or others perform *ruqyāh* on you, whether you are a child or an adult, is permitted if it is an action that they initiated, and does not rule you out (or in, for that matter) of the 70,000 favored as per the hadith. You may also perform *ruqyāh* on yourself as the Prophet ﷺ used to do so.

On the interpretation of the word *yastarqūn* (Arabic: يسترقون) in this hadith, [Abu Bakr ibn al-'Arabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Bakr_ibn_al-Arabi), a hghly-esteemed Māliki scholar, said in his book [*Al-Masālik Fi Sharḥ Muwaṭṭa' Mālik* 8/452](https://al-maktaba.org/book/32847/3788#p7) (Arabic only) that the word *yastarqūn* refers to:

1. those who use charms to seek cure
2. those who do not practice *ruqyāh* themselves but ask others to perform it on them as a desperate measure, or
3. those who do not practice *ruqyāh* without or prior to ailment or illness.

As to whether you in specific will be among those favored 70,000 on Judgment Day is a matter that can only known through revelation, so only Allah ﷻ knows. As per the hadith above, we know that the companion ['Ukkasha ibn Mihṣan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukasha_ibn_al-Mihsan) is one of them, but no other name was mentioned.